# How can I fix this Applied Energetics 2 storage bus problem?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-applied-energistics

I was playing Applied Energetics 2 and when I put a storage bus on my chest and connected it to another chest it didn't work - I saw nothing in the chest. How can I fix this?

[image: storage bus is connected to chest and connected to network]

[image: as you can see i have power underneath connecting to my me chest and the power is working]

Answer (score 3):

**Connect your ME Storage Bus to an ME Terminal**
An ME Terminal allows you to see everything stored within your network, including items in chests connected to storage buses.